# redux call api with while loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am calling dispatch like this:

```
dispatch(check_data())
```

and my functions like:

```
export function get_data(){
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return dispatch(myApi({url: `myurl`, method: "GET"}
      )).then(response => {
        return response.json()
    }).then(response => {
      return response
    })
  }
}

export function check_data(){
  return dispatch => {
    var status = null;
    var api_response;
    while(status != 7102){
      console.log("checking api response")
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("dispatching now ")
        dispatch(get_data()).then(response => {
          console.log(response)
          status = response.status
          console.log("printing status")
          console.log(status)
          api_response = response
        })
      }, 7000) 
    }
    console.log("printing api response")
    console.log(api_response)
    dispatch(reset_data())
    return api_response
  }
}
```

when I do this.. it enters into infinite loop..

I just want to check if the `status` is not equal to `7102` it should again check the data. If found it should return the response

What is wrong in here ??

Comment: Your code completely wrong,
try to use this library
https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst

Comment: Why you dispatch alot of events, may better to get all your items as array and dispatch 1 event when you find your correct status

Comment: can you elaborate or give me hint with my above code ??